# How to export all vue components from folder with index.js?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I want to export all vue components from folder. But I face error with this code

@components/index.js < code 1

```js
import camelCase from "lodash/camelCase";
const requireModule = require.context(".", false, /\.vue$/);
const modules = {};

requireModule.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  const moduleName = camelCase(fileName.replace(/(\.\/|\.vue)/g, "")); //

  modules[moduleName] = requireModule(fileName).default;
});
export default modules;
```

if I export simply, it's no problem

@components/index.js < code 2

```js
export { default as ButtonStyled } from './ButtonStyled.vue'
export { default as InputStyled } from './InputStyled.vue'
```

and I want to import like this:

```js
import { InputStyled } from '@components'
```

Here code 2 is ok, but I need code 1. I tried with this packeage `yungsilva/named-exports` but not ok.

Comment: Create a index.js in the folder and create named exports. For instance: import Component from '@/components/Component.vue' and then export { Component } or in js module.exports = { Component }